# Return mouse position at a given time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the position of something relative to the current position of the mouse.

Is there a way that I can get the current position of the mouse without needing to constantly track where it is?

Ideally can I use the `window` property to find it?

Comment: Most mouse events include the mouse's position, you're going to need to add more detail if you want a detail answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any way to track mouse position you have to use an event listener. if you have to do some different actions while tracking continuously would create issues like freezing.

To avoid these kinds of issues, we have two techniques

1. Event debouncing (listen based on a particular interval condition)
2. Event Throttling (to control the rate of listening)

check out this link https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf